# Displaying image in template with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

So I am hosting some user-uploaded images on my site. I want to have an html page that displays the image inline, and some data about it on the side, etc. I've set up my app with two handlers, one that displays the image on the page that uses a url_for to get the url for the raw image(e.g. i.mysite.com/image.jpg). It displays on the page fine, but takes forever to load. When I remove this function and just generate a URL for the image alone without the page, it loads instantly. Is this just a flask thing that will be remedied in a production environment with a real webserver, or is there another way I should be doing this? The images are not in the /static folder, they are in their own folder. I get the url for the raw image link in the handler for the function that displays the page with the image on it, and pass that as a path to the template.

```
@app.route('/<filename>', subdomain='i')
def uploaded_image(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['IMAGE_FOLDER'], filename)

@app.route('/<tag>/', subdomain='i', methods=['GET'])
def display_image(tag):
    file = Storedfile.query.filter_by(routing_id=tag).first()
    filename = file.name
    return render_template("image-page.html", source=url_for('uploaded_image', filename=filename))
```

Like I said it displays the image fine, but takes forever to load, and when I inspect the image on the page with FF's dev tools, instead of seeing an actual URL, I see something like

```
<img src="/pyhE4eJ.jpg"></img>
```

For the other links, I get actual URLS that are made from functions, like

```
<a href="http://local.dev:5000/info"></a>
```

Shouldn't the source for the image be looking like this too?

Comment: That's because you're serving your images via Flask. Serving big static images with help of any CGI will always be slower than doing that with plain http server. Since Flask isn't optimised for doing that, it may behave strange and slow.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I first thought. I was just confused because like I said, when I hit the URL to display just the image alone it loaded instantly, but it takes about 8 second to load inline with the page.